# BeforeAll in JEST not working as expected with asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

- I'm trying to write few test cases using JEST for testing my API's. So I need the JWT token value in these cases. For getting the token value I've created an asynchronous getJWTToken function. Now I'm calling this function inside beforeAll().
- But I'm getting random results on running the test cases. Most of the times all test cases are getting passed successfully but few of the times I'm getting 403 forbidden error as before getting the Token value my test cases started processing.
  Could someone suggest any workaround for this.?

```
import app from '../../../src/app';
const { getJWTToken } = require('../../../src/utils/app.util');
const should = require('should');
const request = require('supertest')(app);

describe('API Test Cases :', () => {
  const body = {};
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const data = await getJWTToken();
    body['user_id'] = data[0]['_id'];
    body['token'] = data[0]['token'];
  });
    describe('API 1', () => {
    it('Should fetch', (done) => {
      request.post('endpoint')
      .send({
         requestBody
      })
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', `bearer ${body['token']}`)
      .expect(commonAssertions)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        return done();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the beforeEach()?  Same syntax but run before the individual tests?

Comment: If you are not testing your actual endpoint, which takes time, you might just want to mock out the calls.  Mocking the calls does not address your issue, but helps your tests as the mock can return any value and the different errors, so you can see your error handling is working as well.

Comment: @StevenScott I haven't tried beforeEach(). Because here I've mentioned only 1 test case but actually there are many test cases which uses the same token. So I don't want to repeat the same functionality for all.

And yeah mocking will be the last resort if I'm unable to do it with this approach.